# Person Eye Gaze Detection: Identify where the user is looking at on a board

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, vision

I am working on a project where there is board and camera on top of it. The objective is to identify students who are looking at the board and also identify the location of their sight (on the board).

Currently, I am planning to approach the challenge in following parts:

1. Identify Students faces
2. Identify ROI of their both eye from the face detected
3. Identify the location of their eye pupil/iris center and head pose
4. Decide whether the person is looking at the board or not?
5. If yes, which area of the board the student is looking at?

So far, i was able to do the following things:

1. Identify the face and eye land-marks and face position vector (X, Y, Z )

Below is the code:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils.video import FileVideoStream
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils import face_utils
from gaze_codefiles import get_head_pose,draw_border,iris_center
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import dlib
import cv2

line_pairs = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 0],
              [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 4],
              [0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7]]


print("[INFO] loading facial landmark predictor...")
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('./shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')

print("[INFO] camera sensor warming up...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
(lStart, lEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["left_eye"]
(rStart, rEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["right_eye"]
# vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start() # Raspberry Pi
time.sleep(2.0)

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    rects = detector(gray,0)

    for rect in rects:
        (bx,by,bw,bh) = face_utils.rect_to_bb(rect)
        draw_border(frame,(bx,by),(bx+bw,by+bh),(127,255,255),1,10,20)

        shape = predictor(gray,rect)

        shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

        leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]

        rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]



        leftEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(leftEye)

        rightEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(rightEye)

        cv2.drawContours(frame, [leftEyeHull], -1, (127, 255, 255), 1)

        cv2.drawContours(frame, [rightEyeHull], -1, (127, 255, 255), 1)

        reprojectdst, euler_angle = get_head_pose(shape)

        image_points = np.float32([shape[17], shape[21], shape[22], shape[26], shape[36],
                            shape[39], shape[42], shape[45], shape[31], shape[35],
                            shape[48], shape[54], shape[57], shape[8]])

        #for start, end in line_pairs:
            #cv2.line(frame, reprojectdst[start], reprojectdst[end], (0, 0, 255))

        for p in image_points:
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(p[0]), int(p[1])), 1, (0,0,255), -1)

        #p1 = (int(shape[34][0]), int(shape[34][1]))
        #p2 = (int(reprojectdst[0][0]), int(reprojectdst[0][1]))

        #cv2.line(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2)

        cv2.putText(frame, "X: " + "{:7.2f}".format(euler_angle[0, 0]), (20, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                            0.5, (127, 255, 255), thickness=1)
        cv2.putText(frame, "Y: " + "{:7.2f}".format(euler_angle[1, 0]), (20, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                            0.5, (127, 255, 255), thickness=1)
        cv2.putText(frame, "Z: " + "{:7.2f}".format(euler_angle[2, 0]), (20, 80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                            0.5, (127, 255, 255), thickness=1)

        #cv2.putText(frame,"Left Eye Center is:{}".format(tuple(lefteyecenter)),(20,100),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.75, (127, 255, 255), thickness=2)

        #cv2.putText(frame,"Left Eye Center is:{}".format(tuple(righteyecenter)),(20,100),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.75, (127, 255, 255), thickness=2)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Here is the output of the same:

[image]

I was able to get the gaze directions of the both the eyes, now I am just to need to project these vectors on to 3D space in real world (Board or a laptop screen). Could someone direct me on that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a good approach to the problem: you have broken it down to subproblems.

Localize the eyes in 3D. After this you can create a plane on which the eyes are: the vector between the eyes and its normal are sufficient to define this plane. It looks like you already found the face landmarks. If your detections are in 2D you can try something like [this](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html). More information on stereo pair -> 3D conversion [here](https://medium.com/@dc.aihub/3d-reconstruction-with-stereo-images-part-1-camera-calibration-d86f750a1ade).

The bottom picture looks like [GazeML](https://github.com/swook/GazeML). It would help to know what algorithm you are using for gaze and what kind of output it gives. Regardless of that you should have two angles describing the eye directions. These gaze vectors start from the plane we defined in the previous step. Now you have both the starting point and the direction for the vectors in 3D.

If you know only the 2D projection of the 3D gaze vectors but you know the length of the vectors you can use math to solve the 3D gaze vectors. Please refer to [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection).

You might want to calibrate your camera first as they have different kind of distortions. You can calibrate your algorithm by putting a test picture on the board (for example a straight line) and making the test subject follow that with their eyes. Then you can calculate the error and make necessary adjustments.

Good luck!